# Amcharts category axis scale

Tags: graph, amcharts

JSBIN : http://jsbin.com/jiduwiniwe/edit?html

The attached chart has category Axis but axis scale is automatically calculated which makes the graph odd (not how it should look like).

If you see the values along the y axis, it's not uniform. Any idea how to make the Y axis interval uniform ?

[image]

It should perhaps look more like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The answer was rewritten completely as per comments]

It appears, you are using arbitrary values as categories in a serial chart. Category axis does not maintain numeric scale, it just positions each category at equal intervals and displays a category every X'th category, which is a number out of your scale. Hence labels appearing at indescribable intervals.

XY chart would be a much better fit, for plotting data that has numeric scale in both dimensions. XY chart has both axes as value, so it will space out your scale as such, and will display meaningful value labels on both axes.

Here's your chart remade into an XY chart:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "xy",
  "theme": "light",
  "autoMarginOffset": 10,      
  "rotate" : true,  
  "pathToImages": "http://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",
  "path": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/",
  "dataProvider":  [{"v_sec":0,"tvd":0,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:38"},{"v_sec":0.42,"tvd":124.53,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:39"},{"v_sec":0.66,"tvd":152.64,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:40"},{"v_sec":1.02,"tvd":180.74,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:41"},{"v_sec":1.43,"tvd":208.85,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:42"},{"v_sec":1.91,"tvd":236.95,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:43"},{"v_sec":2.4,"tvd":265.05,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:44"},{"v_sec":2.67,"tvd":293.16,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:45"},{"v_sec":2.69,"tvd":321.27,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:46"},{"v_sec":2.52,"tvd":349.37,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:47"},{"v_sec":2.19,"tvd":377.48,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:48"},{"v_sec":1.62,"tvd":405.58,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:49"},{"v_sec":1.04,"tvd":433.68,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:50"},{"v_sec":0.63,"tvd":461.78,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:51"},{"v_sec":0.39,"tvd":489.88,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:52"},{"v_sec":0.47,"tvd":517.99,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:53"},{"v_sec":0.8,"tvd":546.1,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:54"},{"v_sec":1.34,"tvd":574.2,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:55"},{"v_sec":1.84,"tvd":595.91,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:56"},{"v_sec":2.21,"tvd":624.29,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:57"},{"v_sec":2.06,"tvd":652.28,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:58"},{"v_sec":1.62,"tvd":680.18,"date":"26\/02\/2015 16:59"},{"v_sec":1.47,"tvd":689.52,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:00"},{"v_sec":1.37,"tvd":698.86,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:01"},{"v_sec":0.63,"tvd":745.62,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:02"},{"v_sec":-0.5,"tvd":792.41,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:03"},{"v_sec":-1,"tvd":839.98,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:04"},{"v_sec":-0.7,"tvd":887.63,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:05"},{"v_sec":-0.31,"tvd":935.45,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:06"},{"v_sec":-0.01,"tvd":982.78,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:07"},{"v_sec":0.17,"tvd":1030.17,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:08"},{"v_sec":-0.05,"tvd":1077.76,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:09"},{"v_sec":-0.56,"tvd":1125.59,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:10"},{"v_sec":-1.24,"tvd":1172.88,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:11"},{"v_sec":-2.24,"tvd":1220.15,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:12"},{"v_sec":-3.47,"tvd":1267.47,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:13"},{"v_sec":-4.65,"tvd":1314.74,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:14"},{"v_sec":-5.32,"tvd":1362.39,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:15"},{"v_sec":-5.7,"tvd":1409.81,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:16"},{"v_sec":-6.08,"tvd":1457.3,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:17"},{"v_sec":-6.27,"tvd":1505.08,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:18"},{"v_sec":-6.24,"tvd":1552.59,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:19"},{"v_sec":-6.38,"tvd":1599.88,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:20"},{"v_sec":-6.45,"tvd":1647.25,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:21"},{"v_sec":-6.09,"tvd":1694.81,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:22"},{"v_sec":-5.52,"tvd":1742.21,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:23"},{"v_sec":-4.96,"tvd":1789.61,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:24"},{"v_sec":-4.64,"tvd":1837.06,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:25"},{"v_sec":-4.58,"tvd":1884.64,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:26"},{"v_sec":-4.47,"tvd":1932.34,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:27"},{"v_sec":-4.54,"tvd":1980.08,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:28"},{"v_sec":-5.44,"tvd":2033.1,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:29"},{"v_sec":-5.78,"tvd":2046.57,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:30"},{"v_sec":-5.98,"tvd":2056.01,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:31"},{"v_sec":-6.09,"tvd":2065.46,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:32"},{"v_sec":-6.18,"tvd":2074.88,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:33"},{"v_sec":-6.21,"tvd":2084.24,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:34"},{"v_sec":-6.09,"tvd":2093.56,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:35"},{"v_sec":-5.76,"tvd":2102.87,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:36"},{"v_sec":-5.14,"tvd":2112.16,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:37"},{"v_sec":-4.35,"tvd":2121.48,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:38"},{"v_sec":-3.42,"tvd":2130.89,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:39"},{"v_sec":-2.26,"tvd":2140.13,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:40"},{"v_sec":-0.78,"tvd":2149.36,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:41"},{"v_sec":1.02,"tvd":2158.46,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:42"},{"v_sec":3.26,"tvd":2167.52,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:43"},{"v_sec":6,"tvd":2176.63,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:44"},{"v_sec":9.1,"tvd":2185.39,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:45"},{"v_sec":12.62,"tvd":2193.98,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:46"},{"v_sec":16.64,"tvd":2202.59,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:47"},{"v_sec":21.01,"tvd":2210.83,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:48"},{"v_sec":25.82,"tvd":2218.86,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:49"},{"v_sec":31.1,"tvd":2226.81,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:50"},{"v_sec":36.69,"tvd":2234.6,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:51"},{"v_sec":42.2,"tvd":2242.21,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:52"},{"v_sec":47.73,"tvd":2250.04,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:53"},{"v_sec":53.34,"tvd":2257.67,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:54"},{"v_sec":59.5,"tvd":2265.15,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:55"},{"v_sec":66.03,"tvd":2272.08,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:56"},{"v_sec":72.94,"tvd":2278.57,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:57"},{"v_sec":80.2,"tvd":2284.69,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:58"},{"v_sec":87.71,"tvd":2290.51,"date":"26\/02\/2015 17:59"},{"v_sec":95.42,"tvd":2295.99,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:00"},{"v_sec":103.56,"tvd":2301.19,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:01"},{"v_sec":111.77,"tvd":2305.85,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:02"},{"v_sec":120.36,"tvd":2310.03,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:03"},{"v_sec":129.11,"tvd":2313.67,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:04"},{"v_sec":138.02,"tvd":2316.89,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:05"},{"v_sec":147.06,"tvd":2319.98,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:06"},{"v_sec":156.03,"tvd":2323.11,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:07"},{"v_sec":165,"tvd":2326.21,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:08"},{"v_sec":174.02,"tvd":2329.17,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:09"},{"v_sec":183.2,"tvd":2331.96,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:10"},{"v_sec":192.38,"tvd":2334.37,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:11"},{"v_sec":201.63,"tvd":2336.31,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:12"},{"v_sec":211.05,"tvd":2337.84,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:13"},{"v_sec":220.45,"tvd":2339.08,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:14"},{"v_sec":229.84,"tvd":2340.05,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:15"},{"v_sec":239.23,"tvd":2340.73,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:16"},{"v_sec":248.61,"tvd":2341.23,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:17"},{"v_sec":258.03,"tvd":2341.63,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:18"},{"v_sec":267.44,"tvd":2341.93,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:19"},{"v_sec":276.84,"tvd":2342.04,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:20"},{"v_sec":286.22,"tvd":2342,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:21"},{"v_sec":295.62,"tvd":2341.91,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:22"},{"v_sec":305.04,"tvd":2341.78,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:23"},{"v_sec":314.43,"tvd":2341.65,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:24"},{"v_sec":323.82,"tvd":2341.56,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:25"},{"v_sec":333.18,"tvd":2341.56,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:26"},{"v_sec":342.58,"tvd":2341.69,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:27"},{"v_sec":351.99,"tvd":2341.86,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:28"},{"v_sec":361.33,"tvd":2341.94,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:29"},{"v_sec":370.69,"tvd":2341.78,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:30"},{"v_sec":380.1,"tvd":2341.5,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:31"},{"v_sec":389.53,"tvd":2341.32,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:32"},{"v_sec":398.96,"tvd":2341.33,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:33"},{"v_sec":408.53,"tvd":2341.42,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:34"},{"v_sec":417.98,"tvd":2341.52,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:35"},{"v_sec":427.68,"tvd":2341.64,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:36"},{"v_sec":437.09,"tvd":2341.77,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:37"},{"v_sec":446.79,"tvd":2341.88,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:38"},{"v_sec":456.26,"tvd":2341.93,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:39"},{"v_sec":465.7,"tvd":2341.84,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:40"},{"v_sec":475.09,"tvd":2341.64,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:41"},{"v_sec":484.48,"tvd":2341.52,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:42"},{"v_sec":493.92,"tvd":2341.59,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:43"},{"v_sec":503.34,"tvd":2341.66,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:44"},{"v_sec":512.8,"tvd":2341.57,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:45"},{"v_sec":522.22,"tvd":2341.45,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:46"},{"v_sec":531.65,"tvd":2341.52,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:47"},{"v_sec":541.12,"tvd":2341.74,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:48"},{"v_sec":550.61,"tvd":2342.01,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:49"},{"v_sec":560.05,"tvd":2342.32,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:50"},{"v_sec":569.52,"tvd":2342.66,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:51"},{"v_sec":579,"tvd":2343.04,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:52"},{"v_sec":588.44,"tvd":2343.39,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:53"},{"v_sec":598.09,"tvd":2343.68,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:54"},{"v_sec":607.58,"tvd":2344.01,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:55"},{"v_sec":617.21,"tvd":2344.33,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:56"},{"v_sec":626.65,"tvd":2344.58,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:57"},{"v_sec":636.09,"tvd":2344.75,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:58"},{"v_sec":645.52,"tvd":2344.75,"date":"26\/02\/2015 18:59"},{"v_sec":654.98,"tvd":2344.59,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:00"},{"v_sec":664.41,"tvd":2344.35,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:01"},{"v_sec":673.91,"tvd":2344.2,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:02"},{"v_sec":683.39,"tvd":2344.16,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:03"},{"v_sec":692.82,"tvd":2344.13,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:04"},{"v_sec":702.32,"tvd":2344.16,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:05"},{"v_sec":711.77,"tvd":2344.23,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:06"},{"v_sec":721.29,"tvd":2344.31,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:07"},{"v_sec":731.05,"tvd":2344.35,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:08"},{"v_sec":740.5,"tvd":2344.36,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:09"},{"v_sec":749.93,"tvd":2344.33,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:10"},{"v_sec":759.4,"tvd":2344.29,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:11"},{"v_sec":768.99,"tvd":2344.28,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:12"},{"v_sec":778.43,"tvd":2344.3,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:13"},{"v_sec":787.87,"tvd":2344.38,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:14"},{"v_sec":797.35,"tvd":2344.52,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:15"},{"v_sec":806.83,"tvd":2344.66,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:16"},{"v_sec":816.27,"tvd":2344.71,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:17"},{"v_sec":825.72,"tvd":2344.71,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:18"},{"v_sec":835.17,"tvd":2344.69,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:19"},{"v_sec":844.6,"tvd":2344.66,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:20"},{"v_sec":854.19,"tvd":2344.63,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:21"},{"v_sec":863.68,"tvd":2344.63,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:22"},{"v_sec":873.15,"tvd":2344.67,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:23"},{"v_sec":882.84,"tvd":2344.75,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:24"},{"v_sec":892.31,"tvd":2344.85,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:25"},{"v_sec":901.78,"tvd":2344.93,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:26"},{"v_sec":911.24,"tvd":2344.96,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:27"},{"v_sec":920.71,"tvd":2344.94,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:28"},{"v_sec":930.36,"tvd":2344.88,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:29"},{"v_sec":939.82,"tvd":2344.77,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:30"},{"v_sec":949.3,"tvd":2344.67,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:31"},{"v_sec":958.81,"tvd":2344.67,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:32"},{"v_sec":968.28,"tvd":2344.8,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:33"},{"v_sec":977.73,"tvd":2344.92,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:34"},{"v_sec":987.19,"tvd":2345.01,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:35"},{"v_sec":996.65,"tvd":2345.1,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:36"},{"v_sec":1006.15,"tvd":2345.19,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:37"},{"v_sec":1015.61,"tvd":2345.26,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:38"},{"v_sec":1025.07,"tvd":2345.31,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:39"},{"v_sec":1034.53,"tvd":2345.33,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:40"},{"v_sec":1043.98,"tvd":2345.34,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:41"},{"v_sec":1053.46,"tvd":2345.32,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:42"},{"v_sec":1062.9,"tvd":2345.31,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:43"},{"v_sec":1072.36,"tvd":2345.39,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:44"},{"v_sec":1081.87,"tvd":2345.52,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:45"},{"v_sec":1091.32,"tvd":2345.59,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:46"},{"v_sec":1101,"tvd":2345.59,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:47"},{"v_sec":1110.46,"tvd":2345.56,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:48"},{"v_sec":1119.91,"tvd":2345.55,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:49"},{"v_sec":1129.4,"tvd":2345.51,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:50"},{"v_sec":1138.89,"tvd":2345.44,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:51"},{"v_sec":1148.38,"tvd":2345.52,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:52"},{"v_sec":1158.03,"tvd":2345.73,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:53"},{"v_sec":1167.47,"tvd":2345.92,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:54"},{"v_sec":1176.91,"tvd":2346.1,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:55"},{"v_sec":1186.35,"tvd":2346.24,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:56"},{"v_sec":1195.84,"tvd":2346.23,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:57"},{"v_sec":1205.31,"tvd":2346.08,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:58"},{"v_sec":1214.94,"tvd":2346.03,"date":"26\/02\/2015 19:59"},{"v_sec":1224.41,"tvd":2346.14,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:00"},{"v_sec":1233.87,"tvd":2346.27,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:01"},{"v_sec":1243.28,"tvd":2346.32,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:02"},{"v_sec":1252.77,"tvd":2346.32,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:03"},{"v_sec":1262.18,"tvd":2346.28,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:04"},{"v_sec":1271.63,"tvd":2346.32,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:05"},{"v_sec":1281.15,"tvd":2346.51,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:06"},{"v_sec":1290.6,"tvd":2346.79,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:07"},{"v_sec":1300,"tvd":2347.11,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:08"},{"v_sec":1309.42,"tvd":2347.43,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:09"},{"v_sec":1318.86,"tvd":2347.69,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:10"},{"v_sec":1328.11,"tvd":2347.75,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:11"},{"v_sec":1337.52,"tvd":2347.66,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:12"},{"v_sec":1346.95,"tvd":2347.54,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:13"},{"v_sec":1356.45,"tvd":2347.47,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:14"},{"v_sec":1365.9,"tvd":2347.63,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:15"},{"v_sec":1375.38,"tvd":2347.95,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:16"},{"v_sec":1384.81,"tvd":2348.23,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:17"},{"v_sec":1394.28,"tvd":2348.48,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:18"},{"v_sec":1403.68,"tvd":2348.7,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:19"},{"v_sec":1413.34,"tvd":2348.91,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:20"},{"v_sec":1422.76,"tvd":2349.05,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:21"},{"v_sec":1432.19,"tvd":2349.12,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:22"},{"v_sec":1441.59,"tvd":2349.16,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:23"},{"v_sec":1451.02,"tvd":2349.14,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:24"},{"v_sec":1460.43,"tvd":2349.14,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:25"},{"v_sec":1469.83,"tvd":2349.16,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:26"},{"v_sec":1479.19,"tvd":2349.2,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:27"},{"v_sec":1488.57,"tvd":2349.26,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:28"},{"v_sec":1498,"tvd":2349.36,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:29"},{"v_sec":1507.42,"tvd":2349.54,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:30"},{"v_sec":1516.82,"tvd":2349.79,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:31"},{"v_sec":1526.23,"tvd":2350.14,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:32"},{"v_sec":1535.67,"tvd":2350.56,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:33"},{"v_sec":1545.05,"tvd":2350.86,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:34"},{"v_sec":1554.51,"tvd":2350.99,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:35"},{"v_sec":1560.13,"tvd":2351.04,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:36"},{"v_sec":1575.02,"tvd":2351.23,"date":"26\/02\/2015 20:37"}],  
  "graphs": [{
   "id": "g1",
   "balloonText": "TVD : [[tvd]]<br>V SEC : [[v_sec]]<br /><b>[[date]]</b>",
   "bullet": "round",
   "bulletSize": 2,
   "lineColor": "#d1655d",
   "lineThickness": 2,
   "negativeLineColor": "#637bb6",
   "type": "smoothedLine",
   "xField": "v_sec",
      "yField": "tvd"
  }],
    "chartScrollbar": {
      "offset": 15,
      "scrollbarHeight": 5
    },
  "valueAxes": [{
   "position": "left",
      "reversed": true
  }, {
   "position": "bottom"
  }]

 });

chart.addListener("rendered", zoomChart);
if (chart.zoomChart) {
 chart.zoomChart();
}

function zoomChart() {
 // chart.zoomToIndexes(Math.round(chart.dataProvider.length * .0001), Math.round(chart.dataProvider.length * 1));
}
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/xy.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

And here's a [Codepen version of it](http://codepen.io/amcharts/pen/ec23b905adb6cc9d717094c3884d225a).

Comment: No I'm not using logarithmic scale and it's set to false explicitly.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the code. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks martynasma for the heads up. I have worked with d3 before but amcharts is sort of new for me. You have given the right clue.